# Changing the way packages are displayed in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Currently my eclipse source folder display the entire package path and java files under that path. Is there some setting that i change and see subpackages+(java)files under parent packages.

for e.g.

```
src/main/java
   com.company.packageA
       a.java
   com.company.packageA.subpackageA
       suba.java
```

becomes

```
src/main/java
   com.company.packageA
       subpackageA
       a.java
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **Project Explorer** view, click on the little triangle on the right then select **Package Presentation > Hierarchical** as illustrated below:

[alt text http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/282/screenshot004n.png](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/282/screenshot004n.png)